# How to fix windows share issues?

Tags: windows-7, networking, sharing

I've setup a media player for my parent. The media player is directly connected to a computer via a LAN cable. The computer shares a directory.

When there is an outage or issue with internet connection, everything gets lost and somehow the share does not work anymore.

After searching for the cause, I've found out that it is caused because of the master browser. When the connection gets lost, it looks like master browser gets changed and shared get interrupted.

It's easy fix, but it is not for my parent who does not know anything about networking.

Is there a way to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0):

The Master Browser election setting is in the registry:

`HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Services/Browser/Parameters/MaintainServerList`
It should be set to Auto.

Then you can add a new string value IsMasterBrowser and set it to 1 to make that machine the master browser.